A kid gets killed from being tossed into a dumpster
A group of shabby, free-spirited young people living off of dumpsterdiving etc. Two of them are brothers i think. One much younger than the other. 
At one point in the movie, the older brother (or whatnot) leans his back against a dumpster to toss the younger brother, who is sitting on his shoulders, into the dumpster before they all go in to raid it. But the dumpster has some shattered glass in it or something, and the younger brother gets stabbed in the neck and dies.
The death of the brother was kind of a turning point in the mood of the movie. It had a kinda upbeat free spirited feel to it, and the death slowed it down and everything went serious. So I think maybe the brothers had joined this gang.

I think this was asked here before... Do you know the approximate year? Country\language? Genre? Other specific details?

Sadly, this is all i remember. :/ The death of the brother was kind of a turning point in the mood of the movie. It had a kinda upbeat free spirited feel to it, and the death slowed it down and everything went serious. So i think maaaaaybe the brothers had joined this gang. but i dont know :P

@Ssssss please check the answer I have given

Sounds like Mouth To Mouth starring Ellen Page.

Sherry (Ellen Page), a disillusioned American teen living on the streets of Europe, happens across the street collective SPARK—Street People Armed with Radical Knowledge, led by Harry—and immediately follows suit, joining their caravan of orphans, runaways, deadbeats, and punks on a journey around Europe, recruiting new fragile souls. Along the way, a child member of the group, Manson, is accidentally killed when he jumps into a garbage can and hits an artery and his friend Mad Ax (Maxwell McGabe Lokos) becomes heavily depressed

Here is the trailer: 


